# Get the same value of mt_rand

Tags: php

This is the first time I ask a question here, I apologise if my English is bad or i did something wrong here. 
I would ask a simple question, how can I get the same value of mt_rand? Example:

```html
$array = [
          array('colour' => 'Green', 'type' => 'BMW'), 
          array('colour' => 'Blue', 'type' => 'Toyota')
         ];
$random = $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1];

echo 'That car is ' . $random['type'] . ' with colour ' . $random['colour'];
```

But sometimes, it gives the result 'That car is BMW with colour Blue'. I want it gives the right colour when i echo it, like if the car is BMW, the colour is Green, and if the car is Toyota, it gives colour Blue. I hope you can understand what i meant. Thanks for reading this...

Comment: It looks like your code does exactly what you want already.

I've tested it with this https://3v4l.org/MErbF

Comment: mt_rand is run only once so unless this is not the full code it should work.

Comment: That code will _never_ echo a blue BMW. Must be something else or that above is not your actual code.

Comment: Ups, sorry. Just found a little problem in my code. Fixed... (My code is different). Sorry for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use `array_rand` to get a random key from your array.

Example

```
$cars = [
    [
        'colour' => 'Green',
        'type' => 'BMW'
    ], 
    [
        'colour' => 'Blue',
        'type' => 'Toyota'
    ]
];

$randomCarKey = array_rand($cars);
// will be one of 0,1

$randomCar = $cars[$randomCarKey];

print 'That car is ' . $randomCar['type'] . ' with colour ' . $randomCar['colour'];
```

Will output

```
That car is BMW with colour Green
```

If you prefer `mt_rand` here's how you can get a random key, and use it

```
$randomKey = mt_rand(0, count($cars) - 1);
$randomCar = $cars[$randomCarKey];

print PHP_EOL . 'That car is ' . $randomCar['type'] . ' with colour ' . $randomCar['colour'];
```

Will output

```
That car is Toyota with colour Blue
```